# Intermittent connection refused issues when accessing server running Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: networking, server, connection

I have a VPS set up at a hosting provider running Ubuntu 18.04.5 and recently experience intermittent connection refused issues.

The connections can be going through alright for a while and during periods, something like a third of the connections are refused.

I'm a novice server administrator and have tried to get a grip around the problem to my best abilities, unfortunately without much luck.

I wonder if it could be some low level resources that are temporarily exhausted on the server, but have no concrete idea of what that could be or how to resolve / continue troubleshooting.

The problem can be observed if running tcpdump on the server and sending request from my local machine using netcat, eg:

I run the following command on the server with IP 196.189.91.144 to filter out traffic on port 443 coming from my local machine with public IP 196.188.181.138:
`sudo tcpdump -i any -nn src 196.188.181.138 and port 443`

I run the following command on my local machine:
`while true; do nc -z -v 196.189.91.144 443; sleep 1; done`

The output on the server as the traffic is accepted will typically read (four lines per request) containing the Send, Ack, Finished, Ack sequence:

```
12:46:55.760743 IP 196.188.181.138.63571 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [S], seq 1927709909, win 65535, options [mss 1200,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 972740071 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:46:55.854751 IP 196.188.181.138.63571 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [.], ack 612994738, win 2060, options [nop,nop,TS val 972740101 ecr 1086816579], length 0
12:46:55.857747 IP 196.188.181.138.63571 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [F.], seq 0, ack 1, win 2060, options [nop,nop,TS val 972740103 ecr 1086816579], length 0
12:46:55.896751 IP 196.188.181.138.63571 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [.], ack 2, win 2060, options [nop,nop,TS val 972740204 ecr 1086816676], length 0
```

The output on my local machine will say:
`Connection to 196.189.91.144 port 443 [tcp/https] succeeded!`

When the the connection problem occurs, the output on the local machine is `nc: connectx to 196.189.91.144 port 443 (tcp) failed: Connection refused` and the output on the server are consecutive lines with only the Send flag, eg:

```
12:49:09.799827 IP 196.188.181.138.65191 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [S], seq 3362731211, win 65535, options [mss 1200,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 972872973 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:49:11.080774 IP 196.188.181.138.65201 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [S], seq 1348134626, win 65535, options [mss 1200,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 972873986 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
12:49:12.124781 IP 196.188.181.138.65203 > 10.180.53.144.443: Flags [S], seq 3076592770, win 65535, options [mss 1200,nop,wscale 6,nop,nop,TS val 972875232 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

The same problem happens if testing to connect to port 22 instead of 443, so the issue should not be related to the fact that I have a reverse proxy handling the https requests.

I have tried to temporarily disable the firewall (`sudo ufw disable`) but that does not make a notable difference. The firewall is set up accordingly:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
443/tcp                    ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
443/tcp (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

The server is also running fail2ban, but I can't see that my IP address is included in any blacklist.

Ip table rules are as follows `sudo iptables -L`:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
f2b-sshd   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports ssh
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain f2b-sshd (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-ns
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:netbios-dgm
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:netbios-ssn
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:microsoft-ds
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootps
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:bootpc
ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ufw-user-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp destination-unreachable
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp time-exceeded
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp parameter-problem
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             udp spt:bootps dpt:bootpc
ufw-not-local  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             224.0.0.251          udp dpt:mdns
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
ufw-user-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ufw-user-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
ufw-logging-deny  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 10
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh /* 'dapp_OpenSSH' */
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https /* 'dapp_Nginx%20Full' */

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
LOG        all  --  anywhere             anywhere             limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG level warning prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

The server is quite under dimensioned in terms of of RAM (memory usage is typically around 50%) but I am guessing this should not be the concern.
landscape-sysinfo output is:

```
System load:  1.02               Processes:           136
  Usage of /:   41.0% of 28.47GB   Users logged in:     1
  Memory usage: 47%                IP address for ens3: 10.180.53.144
  Swap usage:   0%
```

The hosting is located in a developing country and my experience is that it is hard to get through and / or get qualified help from the service provider, so I turn the community and hope that someone can point me in the right direction, as I'm running out of ideas on how to troubleshoot. Thanks!

Comment: FYI:  Check your system is fully-upgraded; as a fully-upgraded *bionic* system will report itself as 18.04.5, and a result of 18.04.4 could mean you are many months behind on upgraded packages, security fixes etc (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the date of the ISO; installed systems upgraded to 18.04.5 before that date)

Comment: Thanks. System has been upgraded to 18.04.5.